# How to return a scalar value from a Perl subroutine

Tags: perl

I want to return the proper value of `$message_all`, but it's coming back blank in the given scenario. Any suggestions?

```
processing()

print "message_all = $message_all";

sub processing
{
    log ( " Some message");
}

sub log
{
    my $text = shift;
    my $message_all .= $text;
    return "$message_all";
}
```

Comment: Just a comment on Perl style: never call a sub `log`. There is a predefined perl sub of the same name computing the *logarithm*. This may add problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course it's blank - you've declared `$message_all` inside the `log()` function, so it's not available outside of it.

*Always* do this in your Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

it would have told you that `$message_all` is undeclared.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program, especially when you are asking for help with it.

Please post code that displays the problems you are having. Your program won't even compile, and won't run properly while your `log` subroutine clashes with a core function. It never gets as far as displaying the problem behaviour you describe.

You need to *collect* the return value from the subroutine to be able to print it. Something like this perhaps

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $message = processing();

print "message = $message";

sub processing {
  mylog ( " Some message");
}

sub mylog {
  my $text = shift;
  my $message_all .= $text;
  return $message_all;
}
```